# Do I use NSNotifications too much

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I recently found the benefit of using `NSNotifications` when making very custom layouts in my iOS app. I now use them to send data round instead of using delegates. For example I have a `UIScrollView` in one controller, which varies the alpha of a picture in another `view controller`, so I just send notifications as the scroll view scrolls, e.g.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let userInfo = ["ScrollView":scrollView]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("scrollViewScrolled", object: self, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

And observe for this in the other view controller. I know that `NSNotifications` aren't expensive on performance, but with the extent that I use them, and the data I send with them, I wondered whether it would be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question about app design. Notifications provide a very loose coupling, which can come handy if the different components are not directly related to each other.

In my opinion, most of the time using notifications is a poor choice, based on either bad design or laziness. If you look at your code, it's hard to tell how it all connects, who is in charge for what etc. Also, it's pretty inflexible in the way who does what with the notifications. For example, consider you want to reuse one of your view controllers in another place - which probably wouldn't want to fire those notifications. Now the next code smell is just around the corner. You start to patch the notification handling or data just to get this running and to fight the side effects.

That's not to say notifications are bad. They have their use, and it might be appropriate here and there. Just most of the time, it's the ugly quick hack that makes things smell in the long run (and very hard to debug).

Answer (score 2):

IMO they should be used for discreet events i.e. to indicate something has finished for example.
To use them for  sending a continual stream of data as something is changing is not recommended even if there is no performance hit.

They provide very loose coupling but to use them to use them to provide very loose coupling just for the sake of providing loose coupling is not good design in my humble opinion, its gone too far and has turned from a design pattern into a design anti-pattern.
There is no point in making differing parts of your code loosely coupled if there's no need nor no benefit to do so.

Answer (score 1):

NSNotification should be used to notify another entity about a change, not to pass data. You can pass an object with NSNotification to tell the receiver about what the notification is about.

If the receiver receives a notification about, let’s say, a setting has changed. The receiver can check what exactly has changed based on a passed parameter and act accordingly.

If, for example, a data has arrived, you just notify that a data has arrived and than use a shared resource to get the real data. A shared resource can be a singleton, a database or whatever. Hope this makes clear to you.